# db.Set<T>() how to use correctly in EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I observed that we can write custom linq queries if we use

```
dbContext.set<MyEntity>()
```

But can not on

```
dbContext.set(SomeType).
```

I have a context class EGEntities and I have an Entity say "Employee".
How can I assign Employee type Entity to MyEntity? So that I can create a queryable instance of Employee?

## Another Failure Idea

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(thisType);
        GetEntityTemplate(instance, thisType);

// Just to Test

 public static List<Object> GetEntityTemplate<T>(T instance,Type targetType) where T :class
    {
        var Context = new EGEntities();
        var set = Context.Set<T>();
        if (set == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        List<object> l = null;
        return l;
    }
```

But don't know why 'set' is only looking for 'object' and exception is "Model is not current context" though instance is correctly carrying the class instance in the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `DbContext.Set()` method is having another (non-generic) overload that is expecting a `System.Type`:

```
var employeesSet = dbContext.Set(typeof(Employee));
```

And if you're already having a reference to an existing instance of `Employee`:

```
var employeeType = myEmployee.GetType();
var employeesSet = dbContext.Set(employeeType);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: @NilanjanGhosh, And?

Comment: I already tried `code` var r = db.Set(thisType); `code` . But no luck. thisType contains correct Entity Class type. The ResultView of 'r' contains correct list of object, but Linq on 'r' is not possible.

Comment: @NilanjanGhosh, In order to further work with the set in a strongly-typed manner, the actual type has to be known in compile time. You can use `dbContext.Set(theType).OfType<Employee>()` but that defeats the whole purpose of passing a dynamic `System.Type` and you better opt for `dbContext.Set<Employee>()` instead. Alternatively, if you're only interested in casting to a base type (like your `Entity`) you can try `dbContext.Set(theType).OfType<Entity>()`.